# uploading image on server in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, server, uploading

I found this code to upload a file and it is working correctly.

```
<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import = "javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
<%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
<%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.io.output.*" %>

<%
   File file ;
   int maxFileSize = 5000 * 1024;
   int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;
   ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
   String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload2");

   // Verify the content type
   String contentType = request.getContentType();

   if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {
      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      // maximum size that will be stored in memory
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);

      // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
      factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

      // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

      // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

      try { 
         // Parse the request to get file items.
         List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

         // Process the uploaded file items
         Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head>");
         out.println("<title>JSP File upload</title>");  
         out.println("</head>");
         out.println("<body>");

         while ( i.hasNext () ) {
            FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
            if ( !fi.isFormField () ) {
               // Get the uploaded file parameters
               String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
               String fileName = fi.getName();
               boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
               long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();

               // Write the file
               if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ) {
                  file = new File( filePath + 
                  fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
               } else {
                  file = new File( filePath + 
                  fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
               }
               fi.write( file ) ;
               out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + filePath + 
               fileName + "<br>");
            }
         }
         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");
      } catch(Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(ex);
      }
   } else {
      out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
      out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
      out.println("</head>");
      out.println("<body>");
      out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");
   }
   response.sendRedirect("clientupload.html");
%>
```

XML-file

```
<context-param> 
   <description>Location to store uploaded file</description> 
   <param-name>file-upload2</param-name> 
   <param-value>
        C:\Users\saurabh\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Amber_try\web\image\card\
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I need to change the address like this

```
Amber_try\web\image\card\
```

but if I do this, it doesn't work, the code compiles but nothing gets 
uploaded to the specified folder.
How should I change this address?

I need to upload a file on the server this is my project for the final year.
Totally new to programming please be very explanation.

I am making a website which will I upload on some server and will demonstrate this live(as buying a domain is easy and it will secure more marks) but when I will upload this on the server it will give the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "It will give the error" - which error?

Comment: the code is compiling but the file is not uploading to the specified address

Comment: Don't. This is too much java code for a JSP, this is hard to debug and maintain. Split it into a servlet that will process the file upload and use JSP for what they are good at: dynamic HTML